# Access Web interface of docker ngrok

Tags: docker, ngrok

When I used ngrok.exe , I can use this command for setting webhook
`fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels/)` to get this page [image: this page]

I switch to ngrok docker
So, I run ngrok docker by using

```
docker run --net=host -it -p 127.0.0.1:4040:4040 -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=29yEfUG2cgRDobuv15dKkY65ho2_7BRb72Bog882rfDZTx4ZE ngrok/ngrok:latest http 7001
```

[output after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GmGE.png)

but I cannot access this page What should I do for setting docker ? pls help

Comment: what address are you trying to reach. ```localhost:4040```?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PavolKrajkovič I try to reach 0.0.0.0:4040 in output after run image

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. change --net = bridge and map 4040:4040. Use url localhost:4040/api/tunnel to access data